# Navigation bar on the left without overflowing header

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to build a github clone.
Currently i am trying to build a navigation bar on the left with the repos listed (go to your main github https://www.github.com page. The bar on the left)

I tried float: left but then i couldnt do height 100%.
I tried position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; but that "overflew" the header;

Here is the project https://github.com/Eyup3/MintHub.git

Left.js contains the div that im trying to get to work as a navigation bar

Comment: Please post (minimum reproducable) relevant code instead of a link to a github repo

Comment: hello, where is your css area on your git. can you tell me location?

Comment: I used internal css, to have as few files as possible

Comment: Johan im new to react and i dont know in what relation everything is aand what is important. Maybe the crucial part is in a file i didnt post or smthing

Answer (score 1):

I used display: inline-block;.